# GNU MP: Cannot allocate memory (size=4294959136)

Tags: c++, gcc, 64-bit, gmp

GMP cannot seem to allocate memory larger than this amount, despite being compiled in 64bit. I have a simple program that you can test this on, and whilst running it only seems to use up to 1500mb memory and no more. This should be able to calculate the number for even 32bit applications, however since it is 64bit, it seems very odd that it cannot calculate the number. Here is a simple program that runs into this issue

```
#include "gmp.h"

int main()
{
    unsigned int n = 500000000;
    mpz_t output;

    mpz_init(output);
    mpz_fac_ui(output, n);
    mpz_clear(output);

    return 0;
}
```

GMP 6.2.1 installed from MSYS2, Windows 10 64bit, 20h2, GCC

Comment: Please show the error you are getting. `it only **seems** to use up to 1500mb memory and no more` Well, instead of "seem"-ing, profile your code and find out for sure. I have run your code - I got `VmPeak:  6427104 kB` on Linux.  Do you have ~7GB memory _free_ on your pc?

Comment: @KamilCuk the error is the exact title of the question. I have 10gb ram available. What could I use to profile the code given im using MinGW64bit GCC compiler on Codeblocks?

Comment: @asjhdbashjdbasjhdbhjb what's important is that *do you have 4,294,959,136 bytes of free **contiguous** memory*? Even if you have hundreds of GBs of free memory you still can't allocate that amount if there isn't a large enough hole to fit it

Comment: @phuclv I've heard that one before ;). No but srsly, the error keeps occuring no matter how many restarts or little programs running, and it still maintains the same exact number for the error message. I have also thought of this and made another program to heap-allocate a 10gb array of chars. It did this with no problem, so it seems odd that this would be the case.

Comment: It might be informational to remove gmp from the picture, and instead simply call `void * bigBuf = malloc(500000000); memset(bigBuf, '0', 500000000);` and see if that works as expected or not.  If it does work, the problem is probably something gmp-specific; if it doesn't work, the problem is more general (probably something about your environment)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner That works fine. Even works for `8000000000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This situation is typical for using a primarily UNIX-oriented library on Windows: YMMV.

Sure enough, a quick inspection reveals extensive use of the `long` data type ([example](https://github.com/sethtroisi/libgmp/search?q=long)). It's unsurprising that it doesn't work on Win32, where `long` is 32-bit. Win32 uses the LLP64 model, and MinGW follows that ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models)).

Even the [error reporting code](https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp-6.2/file/tip/memory.c#l56) that prints `GNU MP: Cannot allocate memory` is buggy:

```
   fprintf (stderr, "GNU MP: Cannot allocate memory (size=%lu)\n", (long) size);
```

It's actually printing a 64-bit `size_t` as a 32-bit `long`. So you don't see the actual `size` value.

If we fix that:

```
   fprintf (stderr, "GNU MP: Cannot allocate memory (size=%zu)\n", size);
```

Now that prints the true `size` it tried to `malloc`:

```
GNU MP: Cannot allocate memory (size=18446744073709250080)
```

So it's overflowing and/or wrapping around somewhere (probably another `long` variable). [Report](https://gmplib.org/#BUGREPORTS) it to the `libgmp` project. For more exposure can also report to [MSYS2](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues).

Comment: Also, I tried this on the 32bit version, and it outputs this error: `GNU MP: Cannot allocate memory (size=764208148)` which I think is weird since that isn't even the max size of a 32bit number. So something else weird seems to be happening too.